# Qdockwidet area positioning

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qmainwindow, qdockwidget

Basically i am new to qt.i starded to develop app using dockwidgets.i have three   LeftDockWidgetArea.how to arrange one widget in center of the LeftDockWidgetArea.

```
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea,
                  m_private->elementGroups,
                  Qt::Vertical);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dock widget will be added based on the order. Let say you have 3 dock widget with name dock1, dock2, and dock3.
When you add them to mainwindow like this :

```
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dock1);
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dock2);
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dock3);
```

Dock2 will place on the center.